# How to get different key from the following json objects response?

Tags: javascript, json

I need to show `object_id` of each object(response) from the following data.

This is the response i'm getting through Api. Suggestion or solution both will be well appreciated.

---

```
response:{"object_id":"a9951ef0","datetime":"2019-03-20T04:59:23.001Z","ignition_status":"ON"}

response:{"object_id":"8b1546924063","datetime":"2019-03-20T04:59:23.001Z","ignition_status":"OFF"}

response:{"object_id":"9b9d","datetime":"2019-03-20T04:59:23.001Z","ignition_status":"ONLINE"}
```

---

Expected output :

1. `object_id = a9951ef0`
2. `object_id = 8b1546924063`
3. `object_id = 9b9d`

Comment: Could you write a better example? I don't understand the structure. Is there a JSON array that contains all responses?

Comment: Thanks T.Nylund. Actually I've posted the exact response what i'm getting through my api. There is no any json array that holds all the objects.  "resonpse" objects are independent.They are separated by new line. To be frank it is a response of steaming api.

Comment: Thanks. That helped me to understand the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you have 3 different responses with common key in them and you want to take the value of common key from them

If am correct you can you use streams.

Convert the json responses to List of objects

```
[
  "response1",
  "response2",
  "response3"
]

arrayList = new Gson().fromJson(<above json>, ArrayList.class)
```

Then you can get expected values using streams

```
arrayList.stream.map(<arraylistType> :: <keyName>).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

Your API is returning JSON, which is a string. You need to “[parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)” it into a JavaScript Object and then you can simply access the value at the desired key.

```
const parsedResponse = JSON.parse(response);
console.log(parsedResponse.object_id);
```

Comment: Thanks JBallin. Actually i need to get all three object_id from "response" object using loop(i guess).

Answer (score 0):

Following logic could work. The example in pseudo code. Not work directly.

```
# real_response is your message from API.
# Convert it into array by splitting newlines. Use different separator if needed.
responses_in_array = real_response.split("\n");

# Loop through every responses.
foreach(single_response in responses_in_array) {

    # Clean responses before converting them into javascript objects.
    clean_response = single_response.replace("response:", "");
    real_object = JSON.Parse(clean_response);

    // Do what ever you want. To access object_id, just call
    // real_object.object_id.
    //
    // If needed, before cleaning line, check if it's not empty line.
}
```

When you have solved the basic logic to parse the message, you can find better ways or built-in functions that help you.

Answer (score 0):

Solution: I've solved the issue by the following way. Now everything is working fine.

```
     <script type="text/javascript">
       document.getElementById('test').onclick = function() {
         xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
         xhr.open("GET", "filename.json or api url", true);
         //xhr.open("GET", "compose.json", true);
         xhr.onprogress = function(e) {
           var data = e.currentTarget.responseText;
           console.clear();
           var data = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));
           data = data.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm, "#");
           data = data.replace(/##response:/g, ",");
           data = data.replace(/response:/g, "");
           data = data.replace(/##/g, "");
           data = data.replace(/\\n/g, "\\n")  
                           .replace(/\\'/g, "\\'")
                           .replace(/\\"/g, '\\"')
                           .replace(/\\&/g, "\\&")
                           .replace(/\\r/g, "\\r")
                           .replace(/\\t/g, "\\t")
                           .replace(/\\b/g, "\\b")
                           .replace(/\\f/g, "\\f");
            // remove non-printable and other non-valid JSON chars
            data = "["+data.replace(/[\u0000-\u0019]+/g,"")+"]"; 
            var data = JSON.parse(data);

            console.log(data);              
         }
         xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
           if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
             console.log("Complete = " + xhr.responseText);
           }
         }
         xhr.send();
       };
     </script>
```